# Netbeans memory management

Tags: java, netbeans, profiling, out-of-memory

I have some Java code that is throwing out of memory exceptions after running for a while.  I've investigated the netbeans profiler, and when I do one specific operation the Surviving Generations Metric goes up.  However when I reset the program status (not kill it), the Surviving Generations Metric does not decrease.

Why is the surviving generations metric not decreasing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at [What Do The Surviving Generations Metrics Mean?](http://www.netbeans.org/kb/articles/nb-profiler-uncoveringleaks_pt1.html)

Answer (score 0):

Run it under 1.6, and use the Java VisualVM (jvisualvm).

Select your process, right click and choose Heap Dump.

Let it run a while and take another heap dump.

Then use File > Compare Memory Snapshots to compare the two dumps.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem here, but only in the case I profile a JUnit test - surviving generations are growing linearly. When I run the same code in main method, the code behaves as expected.